# Creating image background with giant photo

Tags: html, css, resize, background-image

I would like a background like this website has although my image is HUGE and I do not know how to adjust it to my browsers size. I would also like the same filter/effect this photo has?

http://strategiclawyers.ca/

Comment: I might use the CSS [`background-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) property. Can we see your code and what specifically is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
div.class {
  background-image: url("your_image.png");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Add that to the div you want your background-image in.

Answer (score 0):

Use code like this, same image, same effect:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        html, body{
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0px;
        }

        .element {
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(77, 29, 33, 0.43), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.32)), url('http://strategiclawyers.ca/img/img1.jpg');
            background: linear-gradient(rgba(77, 29, 33, 0.43), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.32)), url('http://strategiclawyers.ca/img/img1.jpg');
            background-repeat: repeat, repeat;
            background-size: auto auto, auto auto;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="element"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

But before you ask your next question, pls try it self.

A good tool is to use the Inspektor on Firefox / Chrome / ...

To use this click on the html element on the page and click inspektor (here Element Untersuchen)

[image: Css Inspektor]

Now you can see the css styles of the element on the right site:
[image: Css Inspektor 2]